# How to call from desktop using usb modem using qt creator?

Tags: qt

I want to build an app to `voice call` from desktop using `modem sim card network`. I want to use qt to build this app.

But I don't know how can i do this. is there any `header` to include for modem support ?

I want to add `qtopia lib into qt 5.5`. is it possible ? If possible how ? I can not install qtopia in windows machine. I have `qtopia sdk`.

Please help.

Comment: This question isn't specific. Have a look at the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: want to voice call from pc using 3g modem. is it possible using c++/qt? How ? found qtopia on google search but dont know how to use it.